# how to disable userinteraction of nsview

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin

I am trying to do something similar as UserInteractionEnabled = false in iOS, but it seems that this property is not available in NSView. I also see that one approach is to implement the hittest method to return null, but the hittest for this lass already has a non-trivial implementation and I don't think I can set it to return null. I found a (deprecated) property called acceptsTouchEnabled, and I m wondering if it can achieve the same thing as UserInteractionEnabled.
The project is done in Xamarin, btw.

```
FreeHandView = new PaintBoardControl
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
            TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
            UserInteractionEnabled = false
        };
```

this is the original declaration of the variable, where the UserInteractionEnabled is set to false.

and this is the implementation of the hittest method in my Mac app:

```
public override NSView HitTest(CGPoint aPoint)
    {

        aPoint = ContentContainer.ConvertPointFromView(aPoint, this);
        aPoint = new CGPoint(aPoint.X + _freehandViewLeftConstraint.Constant,
            aPoint.Y + _freehandViewTopConstraint.Constant);
        if (_hitTestBitArray != null && aPoint.X >= 0 && aPoint.Y >= 0 &&
            _hitTestBitArrayWidth > aPoint.X && _hitTestBitArrayHeight > aPoint.Y)
        {
            var index = aPoint.Y * _hitTestBitArrayWidth + aPoint.X;
            return _hitTestBitArray.Get((int)index) ? this : null;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes hitTest don't work at all try using something like this maybe mousedown can help you

```
 public class ExtendedNSView : NSView
    {
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

        public override void MouseDown(NSEvent theEvent)
        {
            if (IsEnabled)
            {
                base.MouseDown(theEvent);
            }
        }
    }
```